# Whether a composition of two projective transforms is also projective?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, transformation

consider two projective transformations let P1 and P2, whether a composition of these two transformations is projective?

Comment: Any invertible 3×3 matrix defines a projective transformation of the plane. It is also quite easy to demonstrate that the product of two invertible matrices is itself invertible. So the answer is "yes". Having said that, I'm afraid I'm going to close-vote this question because it's about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not programming